# How to query a owl file from protege using owlReady library in python 3.6

Tags: python, python-3.x, owl, protege, owlready

How to load and query an owl file from protege using python owlReady 2 library

Answer (score 4):

**Here, used python owlReady 2 library in python 3.6**

You have to have **owlReady 2** and **rdflib** libraries attached to the project in order to execute this code

---

In pycharm these libraries can be downloaded right away through the IDE

File --> Settings --> search 'project interpreter' --> click the '+' mark then search for libraries and install one by one

[intellij settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RSySm.png)

---

```
from owlready2 import *


class SparqlQueries:
def __init__(self):
    my_world = World()
    my_world.get_ontology("file://ExampleOntolohy.owl").load() #path to the owl file is given here
    sync_reasoner(my_world)  #reasoner is started and synchronized here
    self.graph = my_world.as_rdflib_graph()

def search(self):
    #Search query is given here
    #Base URL of your ontology has to be given here
    query = "base <http://www.semanticweb.org/ExampleOntology> " \
            "SELECT ?s ?p ?o " \
            "WHERE { " \
            "?s ?p ?o . " \
            "}"

    #query is being run
    resultsList = self.graph.query(query)

    #creating json object
    response = []
    for item in resultsList:
        s = str(item['s'].toPython())
        s = re.sub(r'.*#',"",s)

        p = str(item['p'].toPython())
        p = re.sub(r'.*#', "", p)

        o = str(item['o'].toPython())
        o = re.sub(r'.*#', "", o)
        response.append({'s' : s, 'p' : p, "o" : o})

    print(response) #just to show the output
    return response


runQuery = SparqlQueries()
runQuery.search()
```